# OnClickListener calling wrong case

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a listView that is using a CustomAdapter and the listView Item contains a button, I made an OnClickListener in the CustomAdapter to handle the button depending on it's position buy using a `switch(position)` and all the cases are working fine except for the last one which is case 4 when I click it the OnClickListener calls case 0. I thought that there is something in the code of case 4 that is making the app do the instructions in case 0 so I added a log at the beginning of the case 4 but I found out it's being called at all and case 0 is the one being called. I also tried removing all the code inside case 4 and it worked for one click and if I click it again in calls case 0.

Please if anyone knows how to solve this problem please help, Thanks

Here is My CustomAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        final SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        ........

        Button changeSet = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.setBtn);
        changeSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Log.d("NOTHING", "Case 1 called");
                        editor.putBoolean("Clicked", true);
                        editor.putString("TheNumber", "1");
                        editor.apply();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Set 1 selected please press the save button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                   ...........

                    case 4:
                        Log.d("NOTHING", "Case 5 called");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Set is Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.myText.setText(titleArray[position]);
    holder.myText2.setText(titleArray2[position]);


    return row;
}
```

Comment: Its nice if you post code for button's click with switch block.

Comment: Move your onClickListener. Put the onClickListener code before "holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);".

Comment: Define `Button changeSet` same as other views using holder. (Outside of if-else statement) It will work. Your problem is depends on recycle view of List row.

Comment: In other words, you need to set the onclicklistener for each row. Now, you are only settings it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set OnClickListener everytime.Like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View row = convertView;
ViewHolder holder = null;
if(row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.changeSetButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.setBtn);
    holder.myImage =...;
    holder.myText2 = ...;
    row.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
} 

final SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
........

holder.changeSetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Log.d("NOTHING", "Case 1 called");
                editor.putBoolean("Clicked", true);
                editor.putString("TheNumber", "1");
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Set 1 selected please press the save button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            ...........

            case 4:
            Log.d("NOTHING", "Case 5 called");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Set is Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
});
//
holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
holder.myText.setText(titleArray[position]);
holder.myText2.setText(titleArray2[position]);

return row;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    Button changeSetButton;
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myText2;
}
```